# Elastic Stack ( Ingest vs Data node )

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

May I know the difference between Ingest and Data nodes in elastic stack and use of these nodes.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-node.html

Answer (score 0):

***Elastic Stack:*** is a group of open source products ( Elastic Search, Kibana, Logstash, Beats, X-Pack)

***Logstash:*** is data processing pipleline(unit) which takes data, transforms it and pushes it to our favorite "stash(store)" i.e Kafka / Elastic Search

***Master Node:*** is responsible for cluster wide actions such as creating or deleting an index, tracking which nodes are part of the cluster and deciding which shards to allocate to which nodes.

> (edit ***elasticsearch.yml*** file in config folder of elastic search)

```
node.master=true
```

***Data Node:*** holds shards that contain the documents (indexed documents)

```
node.data=true
```

> No shards(documents) will be saved incase of ***false***

***Ingest Node:*** is used to run ingest pipeline (i.e Manipulating of documents before saving it, like removing some useless fields and adding some more information) in other words it is just an simplified version of logstash, It means is just a processing unit.

```
node.ingest=true
```

> If this node is not made data node then it will not hold any shards(means any documents)

***ML Node:*** act as Machine learning node.

```
node.ml=true
xpack.ml.enabled=true
```

> xpack.ml.enabled > The default value (true) enables machine learning APIs on the node.

***Co-ordination node:*** act as a Load Balancer just routes the queries to other nodes that is all.

```
node.master=false
node.data=false
node.ingest=false
node.ml=false
xpack.ml.enabled=false
```

> If all these flags are made false then it will become co-ordination node.

***Voting-only node:*** will participate in electing master node but it will not make itself a master node.

```
node.voting_only=true
```